# Unable to retrieve multi line value using map.get()

Tags: java, dictionary

I have a multi-line value that needs to be processed. I'm using the `map.get()` method to retrieve that value but it seems to be getting only the last line value.

Here's my code:

```
map = new LinkedHashMap(); 
updateMap("BUG", parser, map, bugRec);
map.put(nextBuildIdTagName, nextBuildId); // putting the new value in
String value = (String)map.get(nextBuildIdTagName); // This is where it is not working
```

`nextBuildIdTagName` already has a value, and the new value gets inserted as a new line. I need to be able to retrieve the existing value as well as the new value.

Comment: What does `updateMap()` do? As an aside, you probably want to read up on generics and have `map` be a `Map<T, String>` (where `T` is the type of `nextBuildIdTagName`), so you don't have to do the cast to `String` when you retrieve the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from what I understand you want to store multiple values in the map under single key. Easiest way to do it (without using any external lib with multimap impl) is to create a map of lists like this:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

then when you add to map you can do sth like this:

```
if(!map.containsKey(nextBuildIdTagName)) {
    map.put(nextBuildIdTagName, new ArrayList<>());
}
map.get(nextBuildIdTagName).add(nextBuildId);
```

then to get all the items and iterate over them

```
for(String value : map.get(nextBuildIdTagName)) {
    // do sth to each line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the javadoc for HashMap (of which LinkedHashMap is a subclass), it is clearly stated that: "If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced". To store multiple values (the lines) for the same key, you'd need to do something like:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new Linked HashMap<>();
```

And the add to the list (which is the map value) the needes lines. Note: here I assumed your key  to be a String, change its type as needed.

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put(K,%20V)